How to connect external volume via micro USB to an Android phone?
I am trying to connect an external SSD storage to my Android phone (Redmi 12C running LineageOS 21 based on Android 14), and view its contents.
How can I connect the disk?

An external SSD disk has an USB interface. That needs to be connected to the USB port if your Android phone. Not sure why you try to connect it to the headphone jack, but that port is for analog audio only.

@Robert Well, that's because I have a to-USB adapter for the headphone jack, and not a micro USB to USB adapter. So if connected via micro USB charging port, then the disk should be displayed in a regular file manager?

No, a headphone jack to USB adapter is for audio devices only.

"So if connected via micro USB charging port, then the disk should be displayed in a regular file manager?" it should be, [tag:usb-on-the-go] is the term you want.

Also be aware that the amount of power provided by your phone is limited so you may need a usb hub which can connect to mains/wall power. How much current can an Android phone's USB port supply?

@AndrewT. My use case is as simple wanting the ability to attach a portable SSD to my phone and read its files. From Morrison's comment for example this is not what I imagine is meant... the phone is a host for the disk. The phone may or may not have sufficient power for the disk? The phone's hub has to give power to the disk in order to read it? Is this how it works? Sorry, this introduced a lot of new information to me hence I'm confused.

@Kamil The micro USB-OTG port is very limited regarding the maximum power it can/is allowed to provide. That is one of the reasons this port is now outdated.

@Kamil You should edit your post to include the make/model and OS version of your phone. Having a phone power a SSD is around the limits of the USB 2.0 spec so 'should work' if your phone supports USB 2.0 but you'll need a USB On-the-Go adapter to find out.

@Kamil Based on GSM Arena - Redmi 12C you do have micro-USB 2.0 and as it is a relatively recent device should just need a USB On-the-Go adapter to connect to a portable SSD using a supporting Android file manager app. If you are still having difficulty I would test with a USB thumb/flash drive with the USB On-the-Go setup to isolate if its a phone or SSD issue.

@MorrisonChang The reason why it did not work was because I used the audio input. I have to order USB-OTG in order to test if it works, but as you say, it should work. Thanks!

@MorrisonChang I got the micro-USB to USB-A adapter and the SSD seems to be recognised, but cannot be displayed as an external device in the menu of two different file manager apps. What I mean is, I can choose to view either "internal" or "SSD", but then it prompts me to select it on a menu panel, but it's not there. It should be a software thing?

@Kamil Does it work with a regular usb flash drive? Does the SSD have lots of files? Too many files may delay response but just a guess.

@MorrisonChang It works with a regular USB flash drive with no files instantly. SSD stores +250 GB and has the overall capacity of 1 TB. I'm checking now if the response guess might work out.
Edit: It shows up in storage settings and says it's corrupted (it's not exFAT I guess) - it then prompts me to set up disk as external SD card storage device. I guess formatting it to exFAT would make it readable!
